# How to save JProfiler profiling on Java process kill

Tags: java, jprofiler

when java process of profiling application killed (ex: `kill -9 processId`), jprofiler closing profiling and saying:

> The network connection has been lost. The JVM might have terminated
> unexpectedly. If the JVM has crashed, please try the following
> strategies:
>
> - Reduce the -Xmx value of the profiled application
> - Change your profiling settings (e.g. from instrumentation to sampling) O Don't show this dialog again

is there any way for save immiditly when process killed

JProfiler version:11.1.4

*Edit:*
The killed process is not jprofiler's process, it is java process of which is profiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that, because the process is being killed so no code can run in that process anymore.

Comment: The killed process is not jprofiler's process, it is java process of which is profiling.

Comment: Yes, but the profiling agent is running in the profiled process and it would be the agent's job to save profiling information.